# Does Chicken Scheme support complex numbers? If so, why am I getting this error?

Tags: syntax, scheme, runtime-error, complex-numbers, chicken-scheme

I just started learning a little Scheme, and I'm using Dorai Sitaram's *Teach Yourself Scheme in Fixnum Days*. In said work it is stated:

> *Scheme numbers can be integers (eg, 42) ... or complex (**2+3i**).*

Emphasis mine. Note the form.

Using the principles I had been taught so far I tried writing a few different programs that dealt with the different kinds of numbers. I ended up writing this extremely simple snippet to test complex numbers:

```
(begin
  (display 3+4i)
  (newline)
)
```

Testing this on [codepad.org](http://codepad.org/TKdwSM4J) (which uses MzScheme) and [Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/Kx4VcK) (which uses guile) worked perfectly.

Now, when I tried it with Chicken Scheme (my local development environment), it compiles fine, but when run, crashes and gives me the error:

```
Error: unbound variable: 3+4i

  Call history:

  main.scm:2: 3+4i      <--
```

Apperently there's an unbound variable error, but with my limited Scheme I don't even know what that means (yet.)

Has anyone else experienced this? I know Chicken Scheme is supposed to be pretty standards compliant, and so it seems wierd that it wouldn't support something simple like this. I Googled through their documentation, but I couldn't find anything specific (although I think there is an *external* complex number library available, so perhaps that's a hint.)

If anyone has any suggestions, they'd be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 7):

I believe you need to install the [numbers](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/numbers) extension for dealing with complex numbers in Chicken Scheme. Do this:

```
> chicken-install numbers
```

And don't forget to load it:

```
(use numbers)
```

Comment: I ran `chicken-install numbers`, and it installed fine, but it didn't fix the error. Was this what you meant? :P

Comment: Did you load it first? like this: `(use numbers)`

Comment: No I didn't, actually. Anyways, I loaded it in `csi` and it worked! I also added it to the snippet above, but I still get the error? If you don't mind, could you please show how I should rewrite that snippet so that it would work in a compiled environment?

Comment: Besides adding `(use numbers)`, I can't think of anything else - it should work by now

Comment: @Óscar López Can you show a working example that demonstrates usage?

Comment: The OP mentions compiling code.  That's probably why it isn't working: the compiler's reader is the simple one from CHICKEN core.  There's a [hack to extend the compiler's reader](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/numbers#compiled-code), but it has limitations regarding cross-compiled code.  Luckily, the upcoming version of CHICKEN, 5, doesn't need these hacks; it has full numeric tower support.