# How do I use an egg in a compiled environment?

Tags: compilation, scheme, libraries, chicken-scheme

This is a follow up to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504853/does-chicken-scheme-support-complex-numbers-if-so-why-am-i-getting-this-error). It seems, unfortunately, that Chicken Scheme, by default, doesn't support complex numbers, but rather offers a `numbers` egg that can be installed.

I have installed this egg, via `chicken-install numbers`, and I can load it in an interpreted environment. I can do this by calling `use`; either manually in the REPL, or by running my `.scm` file as a script through `csi`.

For example, this script works perfectly:

```
(use numbers)

(begin
  (display 3+3i)
  (newline)
)
```

when run with:

```
csi -s main.scm
```

But when I compile this exact same snippet with `csc` (even without any addtional flags), I get the same runtime error that I would if I didn't load it (e.g. an unbound variable.) It seems as if in a compiled environment `use` doesn't cut the mustard.

Two other things to note, is that, per the documentation, I tried other importing functions such as `require-extension`, `require-library`, etc., but none make an difference. The other is that if I change the name of the module to something other than `numbers`, say `numberss`, it fails to compile, complaining that it can't load the extension, so obviously it is at least detecting that the `numbers` library is installed.

Could anyone please explain, preferably through a short working example how to use an egg in a compiled environment? Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the helpful information provided by Peter Bex on the [mailing list](http://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/chicken-users/2012-11/msg00143.html), most eggs will work out of the box, you simply need to `use` them.

Certain eggs though, provide extensions to the basic reader, and the compiler needs to be told about them. You can do this with the `-X` flag. As the [documentation](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/numbers#compiled-code) says, `numbers` is one of those packages.

Compiling your snippet with:

```
csc -X numbers-syntax main.scm
```

worked perfectly.

I hope this helps! :)